# Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 while debugging with Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, tty

I have noticed that attempts to open /dev/ttyUSB0 will fail when I am running my code with the VSCode debugger.

The same code will work correctly when I run the program in gdb on the command line.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int reg_fd = open("other_file.txt", O_RDWR);
    int dev_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR); 
    std::cout << "reg_fd: " << reg_fd << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dev_fd: " << dev_fd << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ -g ./main.cpp
```

When I debug with gbd from command line it works fine:

```
$gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/bob/stackoverflowQ/a.out 
reg_fd: 3
dev_fd: 4
[Inferior 1 (process 20129) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

When run inside VSCode debugger I get:

```
reg_fd: 3
dev_fd: -1
```

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I replace "/dev/ttyUSB0" with "/dev/urandom" then both the gdb commandline and VSCode debugger work fine.

This makes me think the problem might be related to some kind of environment variable or environment setup that I need to specify in the launch file.

Does anyone know how I can get this working in VSCode?

Thanks.

Edits:

1. In case anyone finds this and the question remains unanswered. I have found that it is possible to start my program on the command line and then have the VSCode C++ debugger attach to the running process. When the debugging session is established in this way the opening of /dev/ttyUSB0 was successful.
2. For clarification, I'm running this on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with Visual Studio Code on native Linux.
3. My user is part of the dialout group.

Comment: Also, my user is part of the dialout group.

Comment: Update: In case anyone finds this and the question remains unanswered. I have found a workaround. If I start the program outside of VSCode and then attach to the process things work as expected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information. Do not do that in comments.

Comment: You could also post an exact description of your workaround as your self answer, and it might likely be appreciated by others who are researching about the same problem.

Comment: Agree with @πάνταῥεῖ. On first blush it sounded like you were mixing devices on Linux/Windows. I did not expect Windows to have a `/dev/usb0`, and it would be interesting to learn what else you discovered.

Comment: My apologies, it seems like my title made it sound like I was running Visual Studio and therefore running on windows. I am actually running this on an Ubuntu machine with Visual Studio Code. I have edited the post to include this information.